# eclipse does not show any output

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

i wrote very simple database query on java using JDBC. 
here is the code

```
import java.sql.*;
public class statement {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/emp";
    static final String USER="root";
    static final String PAS="1234";
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("hello");
        Connection con=null;
        Statement stmt=null;
        try{
            System.out.println("creating database connection");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"root","1234");
            String sql="update Employee set age 30 where id =103";
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            Boolean ret=stmt.execute(sql);
            System.out.println("return value is: "+ret.toString());
            int rows=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("rows impacted: "+rows);
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }catch(SQLException se)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
```

}

On my last catch - it was just check if program outputs anything. No error and no warning is given. However, on my console window I get

```
0 items
```

message. What is the problem?

p.s. I included all jar files into my project

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Do you not get the first "hello" to print?

Comment: Where is the code that prints `0 items`?

Comment: at console, nothing is printed at all, that is the problem

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting error for that SQL UPDATE statement? It should be *update Employee set **age = 30** where id = 103*

Comment: no, i corrected but the same 0 items on console

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what you typed on the command line or how you ran this?

I cut/pasted it into Eclipse and other than a missing }. I got:

```
hello
creating database connection
hello
```

The second hello indicates the SQLException was thrown as I don't have a database running on my workstation.
I'm thinking perhaps you don't really have the java command right.

Comment: I do not know how to paste pictures. I got message 0 items on the tab where output is usually dipplayed